# twisted.internet.error.ConnectError when run scrapy spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to run a spider and get the following errors:

> DEBUG: Retrying http://xixichengyuanlc.fang.com/esf/> (failed 2 times): An error occurred while connecting: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): : Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.

I have ever successfully run this spider for several times but I want to use some user agents to run faster and get the errors above. At first I thought there might be something wrong with my user agents, so I checked but still can't figure out.And then I want to try the former spider again but still get the same errors.

below is my **settings.py**

```
    # Scrapy settings for soufang project

    SPIDER_MODULES = ['soufang.spiders']
    NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'soufang.spiders'
    DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'soufang.items.Community_info'


    ITEM_PIPELINES = ['soufang.pipelines.MySQLStorePipeline']
    #DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES={
    #'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    #'soufang.misc.middlewares.CustomUserAgentMiddleware':400}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ITEM_PIPELINES` setting is not a `list`, but a `dict`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'soufang.pipelines.MySQLStorePipeline': 100
}
```

Other than that, I can't say what's wrong exactly. I don't see you have set `USER_AGENT` in your settings? Also, paste the full log.

Comment: thanks Lawrence.The main problem is that my ip is blocked by the website I'm crawling. And at the moment I meet another problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028585/twisted-internet-error-connectionlost-when-scraping-web-pages]. Can you give any informations? Thanks a lot!