# How to prevent a twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost error when using Scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, twisted, scrapy

I'm scraping some pages with [`scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) and get the following error:

`twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost`

My command line output:

```
2015-05-04 18:40:32+0800 [cnproxy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-05-04 18:40:32+0800 [cnproxy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-05-04 18:40:32+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-05-04 18:40:32+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-05-04 18:40:32+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy1.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:32+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy1.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:32+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy1.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:32+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy1.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy3.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy3.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy3.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy3.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy8.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy8.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy2.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxyedu1.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy9.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy10.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy9.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy8.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy2.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy8.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxyedu1.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy10.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy9.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy2.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy9.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy2.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy10.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy10.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxyedu1.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxyedu1.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy5.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy7.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy5.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy7.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy7.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy7.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy5.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy5.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy6.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy6.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy6.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:33+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy6.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:34+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxyedu2.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:34+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxyedu2.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:34+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxyedu2.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:34+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxyedu2.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:35+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy4.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:35+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy4.html> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:35+0800 [cnproxy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy4.html> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:35+0800 [cnproxy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy4.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-05-04 18:40:35+0800 [cnproxy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-05-04 18:40:35+0800 [cnproxy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 36,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 36,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 8121,
 'downloader/request_count': 36,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 36,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 4, 10, 40, 35, 608377),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 38,
 'log_count/ERROR': 12,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 36,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 36,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 36,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 36,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 4, 10, 40, 32, 624695)}
2015-05-04 18:40:35+0800 [cnproxy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

My `settings.py` :

```
    SPIDER_MODULES = ['proxy.spiders']
    NEWSPIDER_MODULES = 'proxy.spiders'

    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0
    DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 30

    ITEM_PIPELINES = {
              'proxy.pipelines.ProxyPipeline':100,
    }

    CONCURRENT_ITEMS = 100
    CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 64
    #CONCURRENT_SPIDERS = 128

    LOG_ENABLED = True
    LOG_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
    LOG_FILE = '/home/hadoop/modules/scrapy/myapp/proxy/proxy.log'
    LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
    LOG_STDOUT = False
```

My spider `proxy_spider.py` :

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from proxy.items import ProxyItem
import re

class ProxycrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'cnproxy'
    allowed_domains = ['www.cnproxy.com']
    indexes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    start_urls = []
    for i in indexes:
        url = 'http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy%s.html' % i
        start_urls.append(url)
    start_urls.append('http://www.cnproxy.com/proxyedu1.html')
    start_urls.append('http://www.cnproxy.com/proxyedu2.html')

    def parse_ip(self,response):
        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        addresses = sel.select('//tr[position()>1]/td[position()=1]').re('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
        protocols = sel.select('//tr[position()>1]/td[position()=2]').re('<td>(.*)<\/td>')
        locations = sel.select('//tr[position()>1]/td[position()=4]').re('<td>(.*)<\/td>')
        ports_re = re.compile('write\(":"(.*)\)')
        raw_ports = ports_re.findall(response.body);
        port_map = {'z':'3','m':'4','k':'2','l':'9','d':'0','b':'5','i':'7','w':'6','r':'8','c':'1','+':''}
        ports = []
        for port in raw_ports:
            tmp = port 
            for key in port_map:
                tmp = tmp.replace(key,port_map[key]);
            ports.append(tmp)
        items = []
        for i in range(len(addresses)):
            item = ProxyItem()
            item['address'] = addresses[i]
            item['protocol'] = protocols[i]
            item['location'] = locations[i]
            item['port'] = ports[i]
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Is there anything wrong with my pipelines or settings?
If not how can I prevent the `twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost` error.

I tried the `scrapy shell`

```
$scrapy shell http://www.cnproxy.com/proxy1.html
```

and get the same error as titled.
But I can visit the page with my chrome. And I have tried other pages like

```
$scrapy shell http://stackoverflow.com
```

They all work well.

Comment: this looks more related to twisted than scrapy.

Comment: thanks, then what problem might it be with the twisted? I'm totally new to twisted and have no idea what to do.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

You need to set a user-agent string. It seems some websites don't like it and block when your user agent is not a browser.
You can find [examples of user agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

This [article](http://webscraping.com/blog/How-to-crawl-websites-without-being-blocked/) identifies the best practices to stopping your spider getting blocked.

Open `settings.py`: Add the following user agent

`USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'`

You can also try a [user-agent randomiser](https://github.com/cnu/scrapy-random-useragent)