# Scrapy Twisted ConnectionLost error

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I am learning scrapy and am having a hard time trying to figure out this issue. My spider will not crawl the macys website and keeps throwing the following error:

```
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
```

Things I've tried so far:

1. Setting headers and robotstxt obey per this thread:
   [Scrapy Shell: twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost although USER_AGENT is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470303/scrapy-shell-twisted-internet-error-connectionlost-although-user-agent-is-set)
2. Changing the user agent per this thread:
   [How to prevent a twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost error when using Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028585/how-to-prevent-a-twisted-internet-error-connectionlost-error-when-using-scrapy)
3. Cryptography <2 per this thread:
   [Scrapy twisted connection lost in non-clean fashion. No proxy. Already tried headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924568/scrapy-twisted-connection-lost-in-non-clean-fashion-no-proxy-already-tried-hea)
4. Monkeypatch:
   [Twisted Python Failure - Scrapy Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309631/twisted-python-failure-scrapy-issues)

I also checked scrapy shell "www.macys.com" into the command prompt and get the same error. So I'm guessing the issue is not with my spider. Could someone please help?

Comment: Can you still access the website in your navigator ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your IP from you are launching your scraper has been blacklisted.

You might want to read the following: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned

Also, you might want to tune [the settings](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) concerning the number of requests outputted by scrapy: `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`, `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`, etc.

Comment: I commented out my USER_AGENT and the script worked. Any idea why that is?

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'

Comment: Maybe TCP fingerprinting?